# How I use a class inside another in PHP?

Tags: php

I have two classes. UserModel and UserController.

file: localhost/controllers/user.controller.php

```
<?php
class UserController
{
    public function GetArray() {
        $query = 'SELECT id, username, email, password FROM Users';
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $model = new UserModel();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $model->id = $row['id'];
            $model->username = $row['username'];
            $model->email = $row['email'];
            $model->password = $row['password'];
            $array[] = $model;
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
?>
```

The UserModel class is in another file: localhost/models/user.model.php. The 6th row is causing the error, because there's no references to the other file. How can I do that?

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks to you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [require](http://php.net/require) or [require_once](http://php.net/require_once) to include the other file.

Comment: In most cases you should use `require_once`.

Comment: When I add "require_once '../models/user.model.php'" at the top of the file Chrome gives me a error message and don't show the page. 'Error HTTP {500 (Internal Server Error):'

Comment: leo, not if you are using __autoload() ;-)

Comment: @user1217482: for 500 errors, look at the server's error log. It'll have details as to what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

See the following link. Use any of th method to call a class inside another class. Thanks

[Calling a class inside another one in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846749/calling-a-class-inside-another-one-in-php)